# How to switch between local Project Explorer and SVN Explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I tried to find out how to find local java file of a project in SVN explorer without long "downclicking" projects in SVN explorer. Or rather: how to fast switch between package explorer and SVN explorer in order to locate a local file in SVN. However, I found nothing. I use Eclipse Kepler and SVN Subversive. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: You can right click on a module in Package Explorer, and choose Team -> Show History to see the Subversion history of the module.

Comment: i see only the history but i want to jump to this file from package explorer into svn explorer

Comment: There is no way, other than the long "downclicking" you described.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: if i rename a file in package explorer then i commit it, but the old version of this file is still in svn, so i have to long downclicking in order to delete old version.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the HEAD revision?  Subversion never deletes anything.  It just removes it from the current revision.  You have to refresh the Subversion Explorer to get the current revision after you commit a change.

Comment: example: validate.java is in svn trunk\bla\validate.java and is in package explorer validatePackage\validate.java. Then i rename validate.java into val.java in package explorer and commit it. Now you have two java files in svn: trunk\bla\validate.java and trunk\bla\val.java. Now i want to delete validate.java in svn, so i have to downclick.

Comment: You don't have to delete validate.java.  It's removed from the current revision.  In fact, you lose the history of val.java by deleting validate.java.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use svnCheckout in any folder
Then Put your url|click ok. and your folder will be created,
now import your project in your ide `eclipse`

Comment: I already checked out and projects are imported and i want to find a file which is in package explorer: package explorer (file) => show this file in svn explorer

Comment: Doesn't your Eclipse put the Subversion location of a module to the right of that module in Package Explorer?

Comment: Yes it shows me location, but i want to switch to this location into svn explorer quickly